# Is the cardinality of the power set of $A$ equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{|A|}$ $ |A|\choose k$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was asked to find a formula for the cardinality of the power set of $A$ (the set of all subsets). Denoting the cardinality of $A$ itself as $|A|$, I got:$${\sum_{k=0}^{|A|}}=  {|A|\choose k}$$

Is that valid? I haven't looked up the answer yet because I want to keep trying to derive it myself in the event that the above is not correct.

Comment: You mean $$\sum_{k=0}^{|A|}{|A|\choose k}=2^{|A|} $$?

Comment: Actually the cardinality of the power set of a set $A$ should be denoted $|2^A|$ I think

Comment: What happens if $A$ is an infinite set?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, but you can simplify that equation to $2^{|A|}$, since $2^{|A|}=(1+1)^{|A|}=\sum_{k=0}^{|A|} {{|A|}\choose{k}}$ by the binomial theorem. This can also be derived by noting that a subset of $A$ can be uniquely determined by deciding, for each one of the $|A|$ elements, whether or not it is going to be included in said subset; so the number is $|A|$ 2's all multiplied.

Comment: Thank you! The latter explanation is really simple but makes a lot of sense and is better than what I was doing lol. But it's nice to get intuition behind why the formula I found works as well (forgot about the binomial theorem completely)! Thanks again!